# SSMS All Blocking Transactions report doesn't show Blocking SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am testing blocking scenarios in SSMS.

Connection 1 ( first tab in SSMS ):

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO [ArithmeticOperator](Id, Name) VALUES(6, 'Inserted in transaction')
-- COMMIT TRAN   commented out
```

Connection 2 ( secondtab in SSMS ):

```
SELECT * FROM [ArithmeticOperator]
```

The result is that SELECt from second connection cannot read as transaction in first connection hasn't been commited.

I am running now one of built-in reports in SSMS - All Blocking Transactions.

[image]

Question:

Why Blocking SQL Statement is empty?

I found a query that can display both blocking and blocked queries:

```
SELECT
db.name DBName,
tl.request_session_id,
wt.blocking_session_id,
OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) BlockedObjectName,
tl.resource_type,
h1.TEXT AS RequestingText,
h2.TEXT AS BlockingTest,
tl.request_mode
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl
INNER JOIN sys.databases db ON db.database_id = tl.resource_database_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS wt ON tl.lock_owner_address = wt.resource_address
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.hobt_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec1 ON ec1.session_id = tl.request_session_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec2 ON ec2.session_id = wt.blocking_session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec1.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h1
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec2.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h2
```

[image]

But why this report is unable to do that?

Comment: Use [sp_WhoIsActive](https://whoisactive.com/)

Comment: Because there is no currently running statement. The query you used instead uses `most_recent_sql_handle` which represents the last statement run in the session

Comment: It's also not necessarily the case that the most recent statement on a session is the one that caused the blocking. It could be an earlier one.